Trying to pull a git repository using libgit2's example lg2_checkout
I am trying to pull a repository using libgit2 in C. The library provides an example (checkout.c) and its compiles without error.
When I launch the client without any parameter the print_usage informs me that a branch must be specified.
I have tried to check out the master branch (and not only this branch)
git_client checkout --git-dir C:\Users\me\cgit_test --progress --perf master

but I get this kind of error:
failed to resolve master: revspec 'master' not found
Bad news:
 revspec 'master' not found

How should or what should I specify for branch to be succesful in checkout?

Can you kindly provide A Minimal Complete Reproducible Example of your code so you can help everyone here help you with your question.

I am using an "out of box" code, provided by the libgit2 on its site. Its name is checkout.c and is available on https://libgit2.org/libgit2/ex/HEAD/checkout.html .

Thank you, sorry for the confusion, so you are attempting to run the checkout.c for your purposes and 'master' is not found? I think I know what is happening and it is GitHub's own cluster-fsck in the making. Github decided to be "politically correct" and changed the default branch name from "master" to "main" about a year ago (or so). This will break all code that attempts to operate on a new github repo created after the politically correct name change that still refers to the historic branch named "master" -- double check if that isn't the issue.

Do you have a branch named master? Or are you cloning a repository and it has a branch named master?
When you run git checkout, it will examine the remote branches, and create a local branch for you based on that. So if you clone a repository that has a branch foobar, you can run git checkout foobar.
When you do that, it will say:
branch 'foobar' set up to track 'origin/foobar'.
Switched to a new branch 'foobar'

libgit2's example code doesn't do that. It's not meant to be a complete re-working of the git CLI's "checkout" command, it's meant to walk you through the libgit2 API and show you how it works.
